# Error while installing Homebrew on Mac OS X (10.10.3): Unable to change file mode on /usr/local/

Tags: macos, command-line, homebrew

When I run the command on the home brew website,

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

I get:

```
==> This script will install:
/usr/local/bin/brew
/usr/local/Library/...
/usr/local/share/doc/homebrew
/usr/local/share/man/man1/brew.1
/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_brew
/usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/brew
==> The following directories will be made group writable:
/usr/local/.
==> The following directories will have their owner set to 17oei:
/usr/local/.
==> The following directories will have their group set to admin:
/usr/local/.

Press RETURN to continue or any other key to abort
==> /usr/bin/sudo /bin/chmod g+rwx /usr/local/.
chmod: Unable to change file mode on /usr/local/.: Operation not permitted
Failed during: /usr/bin/sudo /bin/chmod g+rwx /usr/local/.
```

However, I see no reason for this, as I am an admin on my computer.

The file flags and ACL for '/usr/local' (as revealed by `ls`) are:

```
$ ls -lOed /usr/local
drwxr-xr-x     5 root  wheel  uchg   170 Aug 20  2015 local
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your `ls` output:

`drwxr-xr-x     5 root  wheel  uchg   170 Aug 20  2015 local`

That `uchg` flag means the file or directory cannot be changed. You can remove it with this command: `sudo chflags -R nouchg /usr/local`

For more information about file flags, see the man page for `chflags`: http://ss64.com/osx/chflags.html